# Haddock: Document a declaration with inferred type signature?

Tags: haskell, documentation-generation, haddock

Consider the following module

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
module Example (foo, fuh, fon, fuzz) where

import qualified FirstClassModule (Bar(foo,fuh,fon,fuzz), makeBar)

FirstClassModule.Bar {..} = FirstClassModule.makeBar parameter

parameter :: Int
parameter = 15
```

The intention is that the the module `FirstClassModule` provides a record type `Bar` which works a bit like a first class module. Then, the module `Example` instantiates the module and uses the RecordWildCards extension to bring the names into scope and make them exportable.

When you run Haddock (version 2.8) on this module, it will interfere the type signatures for the `foo` functions and include them in the API documentation. Now, my question is:

> Is there a way to document the resulting names `foo`, `fuh`, etc. *without* writing down their type signatures in the `Example` module?

I don't want to write the type signatures because in this case because they are boilerplate. If I have to write them down, this module loses its *raison d'être*.

Answer (score 1):

From the Haddock user manual:

http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/markup.html#id564988

> Note that Haddock doesn't contain a Haskell type system — if you don't write the type signature for a function, then Haddock can't tell what its type is and it won't be included in the documentation.

The documentation is for version 2.8, version 2.9 is the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just found out that, as of version 2.9.2, Haddock will infer type signatures for exported functions. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to embellish them with additional documentation.

For instance, the module

```
module Test (foo) where

foo = "bar"
```

will produce the type signature

```
foo :: String
```

in the documentation, but it seems that I can't add any text to it.

Comment: You can now put a Haddock comment above `foo` and it will work as expected. I'm aware that it has been ~2 years since this answer but you might want to update it.